# How to get the all family id's where Spouse date is greater than Employee date?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, db2-400

Table Name  EE and SP table

```
Family ID   Releation   Date Added
101           EE         1/1/2015
101           SP         2/1/2015
102           EE         1/1/2015
102           SP         1/1/2015
103           EE         1/1/2015
103           SP         3/1/2015
```

Comment: So here I want to fetch the all ids similar to 101,103 by leaving out 102.

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select familyid
from eeandsptable
group by familyid
having max(case when relation = 'EE' then DateAdded end) >
       max(case when relation = 'SP' then DateAdded end)
```

Note:  this assumes that there is at most one record for "EE" and for "SP" for a given family.  It also assumes that you want no results if either is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
select familyid
from
(
select familyid,
max(case when relation = 'EE' then DateAdded end) as eedt,
max(case when relation = 'SP' then DateAdded end) as spdt
from eeandsptable
group by familyid
) t
where spdt > eedt
```

You can try this.